# Google cloud, ubuntu ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install tensorflow on Google Cloud, Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with enough disk space but still i am getting the error "No Space left on device"

df:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            15426012       0  15426012   0% /dev
tmpfs            3087448    8784   3078664   1% /run
/dev/sda1        9983268 7066636   2900248  71% /
tmpfs           15437224       0  15437224   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           15437224       0  15437224   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15        106858    3686    103172   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs            3087448       0   3087448   0% /run/user/1001
```

df- i :

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           3856503    398 3856105    1% /dev
tmpfs          3859306    510 3858796    1% /run
/dev/sda1      1290240 180504 1109736   14% /
tmpfs          3859306      1 3859305    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          3859306      9 3859297    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          3859306     17 3859289    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15           0      0       0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs          3859306      5 3859301    1% /run/user/1001
```

Any ideas how to solve this error?

Comment: Why are you displaying `Inodes`? Add the free disk space to your question using `df`

Comment: @JohnHanley I just followed different threads where df -i was used, can surely add df. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow

Refer to following thread;
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5816#issuecomment-587302775

Comment: Thanks, i tried the command, but getting the same error again.